# Parsing XML with a Namespace in the root element in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am having trouble parsing the following XML in C#, because of the "xmlns" attribute in the root.

```
<CaptureResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/OffAmazonPayments/2013-01-01">
    <CaptureResult>
        <State>Open</State>
    </CaptureResult>
</CaptureResponse>
```

How would I, for example, check for the existence of the  element in C# with the above xml? The below does not work.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(response);
        if (doc.SelectSingleNode("CaptureResponse") != null) 
        {}
```

Answer (score 1):

An XmlNamespaceManager is needed. You create one and add a reference to the namespace in your XML document.

The "s" in the `AddNamespace()` is an example of a Namespace prefix that can be used in your selection queries instead of having to prefix every node with the full Namespace. S can be replaced with whatever prefix you wish to use.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/OffAmazonPayments/2013-01-01");
XmlNode myNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("s:CaptureResponse", nsMgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is ambiguous.  Try this:

```
XmlNode Root = doc.SelectSingleNode("/CaptureResponse");
```